# Why is modifying (by adding extra gates) clock inputs undesirable?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, clock-speed, homework

I am taking a course in digital electronics at university. I am second year mechanical engineering student, but I felt like it was important to understand some electronics. The lecturer in one of the slides, when talking about making a binary synchronous counter out of T-flip flops, said

> It is undesirable to modify clock inputs

I don't understand why this is the case. I have thought about it for a bit, and I can only think of the propagation delay affecting the frequency!? But surely for nMOS and pMOS it's < a few nano seconds. If you only have a few MHz clock the difference is not even worth thinking about.

Can anyone explain why this is undesirable / correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "modify"? Modify how? By whom?

Comment: By adding extra gates in the path of the clock/enable input. @EugeneSh.

Comment: Oh, you better add it to the question to clarify.

Comment: If prop delay is <1% of clock cycle, no sweat but if more then when using timing delays, clock edge must be predicable and stable to avoid RAM errors when running in GHz rates. DRAM in CPU bios uses wait states of core clock to time all the WR,RD,Add delays in counts for RAM by number of core clocks to get optimum clock speed to match prop delay in RAM. You probably have seen this before...with 4 or more consecutive numbers with dashes.

Comment: @TonyM Of course it is clear after the clarification that was added *after* my comment. But what *your* comment is adding to the question?

Comment: @EugeneSh., was fine without clarification. I'm asking you to write clear comments for the OP, if that's OK with you. Can't complain that a question's cryptic with a blunt cryptic comment. Seems fair. OPs are often new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "modify", I'm pretty sure he meant some sort of gating controlled by feedback from the counter outputs. The problem with doing this is that you must be very, very careful that your gate signal is clean. If you are, for instance, turning off the clock when two outputs change, the two may not change at exactly the same time. This produces what's called a skew error (the two signals are "skewed" with respect to each other), and this may produce a false edge in the clock. In turn, this false edge will produce an unwanted transition in the flip-flops, and may cause the circuit to move to an unwanted state. These sort of error conditions can be very hard to spot, and may depend on things like the temperature of the circuit. So it's a very bad idea even to try it, unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more reasons, but I will list three that come to mind:

As you stated, the propagation time of the gates will affect the placement of the clock edges, and can reduce timing margin of the circuit.  This may not matter with slower clocks like the few MHz you mentioned, but will matter if running in a faster system.

Second, depending on what the other inputs to the to the gates are, the gate outputs may end up being partial clock cycles, generating edges that are far removed from the expected clock edges (or runt pulses or glitches) that can clock incorrect data into the flip-flops.

And third, if the circuit design is used in a production integrated circuit, the design may be modified so that it can be tested for defects using scan test.  In this mode, the clocks of all of the flip-flops on the chip must be tied together.  Clock gating can be problematic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Circuits that are designed around a synchronous clock often assume that all edge triggered storage elements, like flip-flops, are clocked simultaneously. The reason for this is that immediately upon being clocked the state of all of the flip-flops change simultaneously, and their new states propagate through the wiring in a couple of nanoseconds in preparation for the next clock/state change. If the clock arrives at a flip-flop sufficiently late it's input data can change before it has a chance to process it. So a design intended to run on a single synchronized clock will fail because some devices are receiving what is essentially a different clock signal, derived from the original clock, but a delayed version.

If you modify the path of the clock to some of the flip-flops using some type of additional logic you could delay it sufficiently to cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying clocks, he means gating them in any way to produce a new clock coming from a logic gate.

That's often tempting to do in an FPGA/CPLD: ANDing off clocks for control or to get low power, running a counter and taking the output of a flip-flop as a new CLKIN-divided-by-n clock. An example might be in making a communications controller (I2C, UART, SPI) by producing a clock near bit frequency.

The problem is it produces a new clock (call it CLKG) that changes just after the original CLKIN does.

This is shown below, with DFF1's output changing just as DFF2 is clocking in its level. This can cause DFF2 to go metastable or to take the wrong level because DFF1's output voltage hadn't transitioned far enough.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJBH6l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This might be the situation in your comms controller circuit, passing data bytes from the fast CLKIN logic to the CLKG shift register for transmission.

It is possible to design gated clock circuits perfectly well, circuits that design out these problems or get round them. You'll see them routinely in ASICs. But the circuit is more complicated to design and maintain by others. The simplest and most reliable clock scheme is a single logic clock going from a PLL or input pin to all flip-flop clocks, the synthesis software will require the least effort from you to produce a reliable circuit. Use more than one clock domain sparingly and because you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0):

First, you seem to underestimate the importance of propagation delays. A few nanosecods of clock skew is **a lot**, even on low frequencies. Having your clock pulse *advanced* by 5-10 ns is not so bad, because you will be violating your **setup times**, and derating your circuit e.g. from 10 MHz to 9 MHz will counter that. Having your clock *delayed* is much worse, as you will be violating **hold times**, and simply running your design at a slower clock rate won't help. Of course, if the clock pulse arrives in advance for one trigger, the clock on the next trigger will appear to be delayed, so the worst case is almost guaranteed to happen.

Second (and more importantly), **combinatorial circuits are prone to *hazards*** or *glitches*, as described e.g. [here](http://www.doe.carleton.ca/~jknight/97.267/267_04W/Asch1HazShortJ.pdf):

[image]

Hazards will produce additional rising/falling edges on your signal before it reaches a stable value. That doesn't matter too much for data signals which are sampled at the end of the clock cycle when they are stable. In a clock circuit however, such glitches will result in undefined behavior because they will produce additional clock edges and violate timing requirements of all your triggers.